# Can I use the same router nut for a 6mm collet on the Makita RT0701C?

Tags: router, router-bit

I am using the Makita RT0701C along with the OneFinity CNC. I needed a 6mm shank router bit for some inlays I am doing so I ordered a 6mm collet from bits and bits.

Is it okay if I use the same nut that I used with the 1/4" collet or do I need a new router nut for the 6mm collet?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. What matters here is the *external measurement*, not the hole that will grip the shanks of bits. As one or more previous Q&As here have highlighted you probably shouldn't take a risk with close-but-not-matching fits on routers because of the extremely high speeds they run at. But, if the outside measurements are basically the same then you could be OK. So, do you have a micrometer or reliable digital caliper to confirm exterior sizing?

Comment: No direct experience w/ that model, but generally, the nut for a 1/4” collet should work on a 6mm collet. The only question is convenience: if the nut snaps onto the collet (like in a PC 690), then it’s nice to have a complete unit.